# Passing object key as parameter to function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function to perform operations on the Array.
I am passing object key and array as parameter to run the function. The function fails at finding the index of key passed. Please help me understanding how to pass the object key as parameter to the function to perform the operations.

```
  const [addOn, setAddOn] = useState([
    {
      itemName: 'Honey',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '20',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326411/Piatto/Icons/honey_ji1muy.svg'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Pickle',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '30',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326410/Piatto/Icons/food-and-restaurant_th26ol.svg'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Eggs',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '300',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326408/Piatto/Icons/egg_a95mqk.svg'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Cheese',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '3',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326405/Piatto/Icons/cheese_cicwad.svg'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Bacon',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '399',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326404/Piatto/Icons/Bacon_yi7qvy.png'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'Chicken',
      isChecked: false,
      itemPrice: '400',
      itemImgURL:
        'https://res.cloudinary.com/antilibrary/image/upload/v1593326406/Piatto/Icons/chicken_qxzicr.svg'
    }
  ]);
```

```
  const updateAddonData = e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      const createUpdatedArray = (key, Array) => {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(addOn);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        const objIndex = Array.findIndex(obj => obj.key === e.target.value);
        console.log(objIndex);
        const updatedObj = { ...Array[objIndex], isChecked: true };
        const updatedNewAddData = [updatedObj];

        const updatedArray = [
          ...Array.slice(0, objIndex),
          updatedObj,
          ...Array.slice(objIndex + 1)
        ];
        return { updatedNewAddData, updatedArray };
      }; /**
       *       const objIndex = addOn.findIndex(obj => obj.itemName === e.target.value);

      const updatedObj = { ...addOn[objIndex], isChecked: true };
      const updatedNewAddData = [updatedObj];

      const updatedAddOn = [
        ...addOn.slice(0, objIndex),
        updatedObj,
        ...addOn.slice(objIndex + 1)
      ];
       */

      let { updatedNewAddData, updatedArray } = createUpdatedArray(
        `itemName`,
        addOn
      );

      setAddOn(updatedArray);
      setAddOnData(addOnData.concat(updatedNewAddData));
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `useState` here? Maybe consider using `useReducer`?

Comment: Yes.. Would like to use the useState.. I am trying to refactor the code by passing the key and array as parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
const objIndex = Array.findIndex(obj => obj[key] === e.target.value);

Additionally,change the param name to "addOn" instead of "Array" in "createUpdatedArray" function.

You are passing the object key correctly, but using it the wrong way. This way, it will look for a "key" named field in "obj".

Comment: I intend to use the function in other components hence re-factoring it to handle the any array and key..Can you suggest better way of doing it..

Comment: I don't see any issue, the way you are passing _key-name_ & _array variable_ . I just mentioned that you should a generic parameter name (like _AddOnCollection_ ) instead of _Array_ as **Array** is a reserved word for **Array Class**.

Comment: const DeleteAndUpdateArray = (key, Array) => {
        const newData = Array.filter(obj => obj[key] !== e.target.value);
        const objIndex = Array.findIndex(obj => obj[key] === e.target.value);
        const updatedObj = { ...Array[objIndex], isChecked: false };
        const updatedArray = [
          ...Array.slice(0, objIndex),
          updatedObj, ...Array.slice(objIndex + 1) ];
        return { newData, updatedArray };
      };
      let { newData, updatedArray } = DeleteAndUpdateArray(`itemName`, addOn);
      setAddOn(updatedArray);
      setAddOnData(newData);

Comment: I am trying to apply same logic to other scenario the same return entire array

Comment: @SagarMahadik: 
const DeleteAndUpdateArray = (key, collection) => { 
  const newData = collection.filter(obj => obj[key] !== e.target.value); 
  const objIndex = collection.findIndex(obj => obj[key] === e.target.value); 
  const updatedObj = { ...collection[objIndex], isChecked: false }; 
  collection[objIndex] = updatedObj;
  const updatedArray = [...collection];
  /*
  newData = [updatedObj];
  */
  return { newData, updatedArray }; 
}; 
let { newData, updatedArray } = DeleteAndUpdateArray(itemName, addOn);